# Replace all text (wildcard) in file with a starting point Publisher=" {GUID} and ending with a "

Tags: powershell

So each file has a line with

> Publisher="GUID here"

I want to replace all the guid's with a simple text "TEXTHERE" (with the quotes)
(Powershell)

This is what I have simplified;

```
 `

enter code here`$list = Get-ChildItem -Path:'C:\AppOutput\*allfiles.xml*' -Recurse
    $replacestring = 'APPXSIGNCERTIFICATE'
    $appxmltest = 'C:\AppOutput\app.xml'

ForEach ($file in $list)
        {

       (Get-Content $file) -replace "Publisher=""`*", 'Publisher="TEXTHERE"' | Set-Content     c:\test2.xml
       }
```

It replaces ONLY the Publisher=" with Publisher="TEXTHERE"{GUID}"

any suggestions?

Im trying to find a way to tell it Publisher=" starts and everything in between that and the next "

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`-replace` uses regex to match the text it should replace, so try something like this:

```
-replace '(?<=Publisher=").*?(?=")', 'TEXTHERE'
```

Comment: THANKS!!! Both of these answers worked! I will have to readup on the regex more to understand it completely but you guys helped a bunch

Comment: Np. the first part `(?<=something)` is a lookahead which tries to find something in front of what you're looking for. `(?=something)` is a lookbehind that looks for something right after your target. `.*?` looks for all(`*`) characters(`.`), with a lazy(`?`) tag that stops it as soon as possible. I added the lazy option to avoid a situation where it would go past the first double-quote sign(which I wanted in the lookbehind instead). I'm not sure if that made it any clearer, but I tried, hehe :P  Merry Christmas

Comment: Totally, so the (?<Publisher=" finds the start and ?=") is the next break point? than the .*? tells it everything between start and end gets replaced.. I kept trying to use \ to escape but I see this example you don't need to

Comment: Correct. `\` is only needed to escape special-characters in regex, like `.` (any character). If you wanted a puntuaction, you'd need to escape it like `\.` .

Answer (score 2):

It looks like your trying to use wildcard syntax for your match argument.  -replace is expecting a regular expression.

Try this:

```
(Get-Content $file) -replace 'Publisher=".*?"', 'Publisher="TEXTHERE"' | Set-Content c:\test2.xml
```

see:

```
get-help about_regular_expressions
```