# PowerShell: Remove Text from Variable using Wildcard

Tags: regex, powershell

I was reading about using RegEx in a `-replace` object [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20756520/replace-all-text-wildcard-in-file-with-a-starting-point-publisher-guid-and), but the solution and the problem aren't quite what I am facing.

If I have the following variable:

```
$FinalOutput = Warning123 for Item: XYZ. Cannot specify "specific" object. Ignoring. Warning123 for Item: ABC. Cannot specify "specific" object. Ignoring. Error Found: Sending error to output.
```

Then use a simple `-replace` to change the variable from all-inline to individual lines:

```
$FinalOutput = ($FinalOutput -replace "Warning123", "`nWarning123")
```

I'm now stuck with:

```
Warning123 for Item: XYZ. Cannot specify "specific" object. Ignoring.
Warning123 for Item: ABC. Cannot specify "specific" object. Ignoring.
Error Found: Sending error to output.
```

My variable will always have warnings and I wish to remove those values that start with `Warning123`. Almost as if I wrote `$FinalOutput = ($FinalOutput -replace "Warning123*", "")`. However, wildcards do not work in the `-replace` object. My end result should look like:

```
$FinalOutput
Error Found: Sending error to output.
```

[Using RegEx](https://regex101.com/r/1iG1og/2), I figured I could capture the start of the string with my specific phrase and then infidelity remove the characters after that string, leaving me with nothing:

```
^.*?Warning123 for Item:(.*)
```

However, that doesn't seem to work either. Any ideas or help on this solution?

Comment: What is your expected output? All without the sentences starting with `Warning123`? Try `^\s*Warning123 for Item:([^.]*)\.\s*`, see https://regex101.com/r/1iG1og/3

Comment: can you split on `Error Found:`, grab the last item from that split, and then trim the result?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew
Yes, the expected output is to have delete everything expect that *Error Found* line.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey
Split won't help me here because it would put that into an array.

Comment: Aha, so you need `^(?!\s*Warning123 for Item:).+` or  `^(?!\s*Warning123 for Item:).*\n?`

Comment: @Masterchiefxx17 - that is an acceptable intermediate step in most cases. [*grin*] if not for your current case, then go with regex. however, regex is more difficult to understand ... and therefor tends to be more difficult to maintain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$pattern = [regex]"(Warning123).*(object.)"

$FinalOutput = 'Warning123 for Item: XYZ. Cannot specify "specific" object. Ignoring. Warning123 for Item: ABC. Cannot specify "specific" object. Ignoring. Error Found: Sending error to output.'

$FinalOutput = ($FinalOutput -replace $pattern, "")
```

Outputs:
`PS C:\> $FinalOutput Ignoring. Error Found: Sending error to output.`

Try that!

Comment: This comes very close, but I wouldn't want to include the "Ignoring" section. I want to be left with just "Error Found: Sending error to output."
I know this is a pain, but since a human may read this log, I need to maintain the `$FinalOutput = ($FinalOutput -replace "Warning123", "'nWarning123")` which helps readability.

Comment: So look at my regex. It's really simple. It's looking for `Warning123` and `object.` and everything inbetween. So try `$pattern = [regex]"(Warning123).*(Ignoring.)"`

Comment: Ah, I see. I thought Object was a very specific RegEx parameter, not just a general "string". Thank you sir!